# Prove that these loops are homotopic

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Let $G$ be a topological group with identity element $e$. Let $f,g: (S^1, (1,0)) \to (G,e)$ be loops in $G$ with base point $e$.
 We define $f * g: (S^1, (1,0)) \to (G,e)$ by $$f * g(s) = f(t) \cdot g(t)$$ where $\cdot$ is the group multiplication. 
Then $fg$ and$ f*g$ are homotopic.

[Note: $fg$ denotes the "concatenation" of $f$ and $g$, i.e. we first walk the $f$ and then $g$, both at double speed.]

So we need to find a homotopy from $fg$ to $f*g$. I've tried writing down various possible homotopies but none of them worked and I can't seem to figure it out. I appreciate any hint.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Hint** : Consider $(f e) * (e g)$. This is obviously homotopic to $f * g$. Can you also show that this is homotopic to $fg$?

Edit : Here's the whole solution, posted on request from the OP.

By definition of path concatenations, $fe : [0, 1] \to G$ is the path $$fe(t) = \begin{cases} f(2t) & 0 \leq t \leq \tfrac{1}{2} \\ e(2t-1) = e & \tfrac{1}{2} \leq t \leq 1 \end{cases}$$ And $eg : [0, 1] \to G$ is the path $$eg(t) = \begin{cases} e(2t) = e & 0 \leq t \leq \tfrac{1}{2} \\ g(2t-1) & \tfrac{1}{2} \leq t \leq 1 \end{cases}$$

Thus, $$(fe) * (eg) = \begin{cases} f(2t) * e & 0 \leq t \leq \tfrac{1}{2} \\ e * g(2t-1) & \tfrac{1}{2} \leq t \leq 1 \end{cases} \\ \;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\; = \begin{cases} f(2t) & 0 \leq t \leq \tfrac{1}{2} \\ g(2t-1) & \tfrac{1}{2} \leq t \leq 1 \end{cases}$$

Which is just the path $fg$. Hence, $f * g \sim (fe) * (eg) \sim fg$, and the homotopy follows.

Comment: I know that the answer was given long time ago, but can I ask you, please.

Comment: @Jane Sure, ask away what you want to ask.

Comment: do you use the path-connectedness of $G$ here?

Comment: @Jane Yes, of course.

Comment: but if $f$ and $g$ are loops and $e$ is constant map, why do we need path connectedness?

Comment: @Jane To homotope stuff. Of course, you can do these in path-components, but you need to be careful.

Comment: ah, you mean the path-connectedness of $G$ guarantee the homotopy between $f*g$ and $fg$?

Comment: @Jane Somewhat. But as I said, you can do all of these in the path compoenent of $e$ in $G$.

Comment: I see now, thank you very much!